# Не работает Facebook Deferred Deeplink

Tags: android, android-studio, facebooksdk

Всем привет! Прошу помочь мне с отложенными диплинками фейсбук. Все делал по инструкции но они не работают. Тестирую через Помощник по рекламе, пишет что приложение запрашивает диплинк но почему-то его не получает
Код копировал с документации
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking/

Comment: Справились ли с задачей, Дима?

Comment: Если вы тестируете на эмуляторе или живом телефоне, то там должен быть установлен фейсбук и залогинен аккаунт привязанный к акку разраба фб. Но кусок кода в студию облегчил бы процесс понимания вашей проблемы